# not getting the response from the webserver for the request GET /

Tags: networking, firewall, telnet

When I **telnet** my server it is getting connected, however after telnet connection if I request for **GET /**, it is not giving any response. But, after telnet connection if I request for **GET / HTTP/1.1**, it is giving me response. May I know this is a firewall issue as Im not getting response for **GET /** but getting for **GET / HTTP/1.1**

Comment: `GET /` is not a properly formed http request.

Comment: @lain not sure why GET / is working for the other 3

Comment: someone down voted it :(, not sure why as it is an issue  that im facing currently

Comment: OK, so here's the problem, your question is pretty crappy. You've chucked some stuff at the internet and screamed HALP! in the hope that someone will take pity on you and hold your hand through a series of reverse Q&A to help you troubleshoot your problem. You have not provided anywhere near sufficient information for anyone to answer your question. You need tech support and that is not what SF provides.

Comment: @lain ok got it

Answer (score 3):

The original [HTTP 0.9](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html) protocol allowed the use of a single GET without specifying either protocol of hostname. For example:

`GET /index.html`

To use HTTP 1.0, you need to specify the protocol, however the Host header field had yet to be defined by [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945) so is not required. Example HTTP 1.0 request:

`GET /index.html HTTP/1.0`

For HTTP 1.1, you need to specify the protocol AND Host header as per [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5.1.2):

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
```

It is possible that your webservers have support for different versions of the HTTP protocol and therefore some accept the HTTP 0.9 style request whilst other, newer servers, don't.

Comment: Hi Mark, is "GET /index.html"  same as "GET /", thanks for your answer :)

Comment: It depends. `GET /` will return whichever file has been set as root on the server, however this doesn't necessarily have to be `index.html`, but it is quite common.

Comment: Also, I have done curl --head for all the severs , somehow I got 1.1 as HTTP protocol version.

Comment: Curl (and most other CLI or GUI based web clients) uses HTTP 1.1 unless you tell it otherwise. The `-0` flag can be used to send the request using HTTP 1.0 ([source](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html))

Answer (score 1):

While simple web servers may respond to "GET /", it is not a proper/true/compliant request, so either a firewall or even the web server is not parsing and processing the request.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068#section-5.1

Comment: Hi Slass, thanks for your answer :), we have 3 more webservers for which this "GET /" is working not sure not for a particular webserver it is not working

Comment: Just use "GET / HTTP/1.1" for all the servers, it _should_ work for all of them.

Comment: "GET /HTTP/1.1" is not working for the other 2 servers

Comment: I assume you are trying with "GET<space>/<space>HTTP/1.1".  Looks like a <space> is missing in the comment above.  Maybe test with "wget" or "curl" and look at how these command-line apps format the request.